# Crashing my Laptop While Rendering a Single Frame

Tags: rendering, performance

I created a NPR Scene not so Heavy. This scene work fine in Viewport(EEVEE) and gives me fine performance in viewport but whenever I hit F12 to render it, My whole Laptop Crashes. I tried rendering another files which works fine. I Tried to move all object to a new file but Still Its Crashing my Laptop.
I have a Fine Gaming Laptop and I rendered more heavy Scene than this.

I am currently using Blender 3.5
Graphics Driver is All Up to date (NVIDIA studio driver)

Specs-
16gb ram
RTX3060 6gb
Ryzen 5

Yo can test file after downloading from here.
https://we.tl/t-4p0O3nv622

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.